# Trying to get no space except 1px border between tables nested in tables

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I have some `table tr td table`s that I would like to have no space between them except for a `1px solid white` `border`, both horizontally and vertically. In other words, I want my tables, which are elements of a larger table, to have 1px border and no more space between them. This is my CSS at the moment:

```
table tr td table {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

How do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Try using `border-collapse: collapse;` and see if that helps. You might need to remove any cell padding, but by default, there shouldn't be any.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle that replicates the issue you're having?